# F# type error with unresolved type at compile time

Tags: f#

I'm trying an experiment where I am wrapping some arrays to ensure the units on the index. I am getting a compiler error on the last line of code here. It is saying that the type parameter 'Value' cannot be used since the type parameter cannot be resolved at compile time.  I cannot figure out why this is causing an error. I also tried changing the method signature to restrict the `'Value` to be the same in both arrays.

```
type ImArr<[<Measure>] 'Index, 'Value>(values: array<'Value>) =
    // We want to make sure we have our own copy to protect against mutation
    let values = values |> Array.copy

    member internal _.Values = values

    member this.Item
        with get(index: int<'Index>) =
            values.[int index]


type Arr<[<Measure>] 'Index, 'Value>(values: array<'Value>) =
    // We want to make sure we have our own copy to protect against mutation
    let values = values |> Array.copy

    member internal _.Values = values

    member inline _.Add (x: ImArr<'Index,_>) =
        if values.Length <> x.Values.Length then
            invalidArg (nameof x) "Cannot add arrays of different lengths"

        for idx = 0 to values.Length - 1 do
            values.[idx] <- values.[idx] + x.Values.[idx] // Error on this line
```

The other method signature I tried which also raises an error.

`member inline _.Add (x: ImArr<'Index,_>) =`

Image of error message:
[image]

I also tried pulling the work out into a separate function and got the same result.

```
type ImArr<[<Measure>] 'Index, 'Value>(values: array<'Value>) =
    // We want to make sure we have our own copy to protect against mutation
    let values = values |> Array.copy

    member internal _.Values= values

    member this.Item
        with get(index: int<'Index>) =
            values.[int index]


type Arr<[<Measure>] 'Index, 'Value>(values: array<'Value>) =
    // We want to make sure we have our own copy to protect against mutation
    let values = values |> Array.copy

    member this.Item
        with get(index: int<'Index>) =
            values.[int index]

        and set(index: int<'Index>) (value: 'Value) =
            values.[int index] <- value

    member internal _.Values = values


module Helpers =

    let inPlaceAdd<[<Measure>] 'Index, 'Value> (a: Arr<'Index, 'Value>) (b: ImArr<'Index, 'Value>) =
        let mutable i = 0;
        while i < a.Values.Length && i < b.Values.Length do
            a.Values.[i] <- a.Values.[i] + b.Values.[i] // ERROR
            i <- i + 1
```

And the compiler error

```
              a.Values.[i] <- a.Values.[i] + b.Values.[i]
  ----------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(31,29): error FS0001: The declared type parameter 'Value' cannot be used here since the type parameter cannot be resolved at compile time
```

Comment: Generic math is still hard in F#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with the F# compiler: it's better to let F# compiler infer constraints than write them by hand.

Here's a solution that allows F# compiler to infer it:

```
module Helpers =

    let inline inPlaceAdd<[<Measure>] 'Index, .. > (a: Arr<'Index, 'Value>) (b: ImArr<'Index, 'Value>) : unit =
        let mutable i = 0;
        while i < a.Values.Length && i < b.Values.Length do
            a.Values.[i] <- a.Values.[i] + b.Values.[i] // ERROR
            i <- i + 1
```

Easier to write, and it doesn't produce any warning.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main problem here is that the compiler doesn't know how to add two generic `'Value`s together. Since the compiler can't infer how to do this, you probably need to give it a hint via [statically resolved type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters) (SRTP), which are, unfortunately, very flaky in F#. By trial and error, I came up with a version of your helper function that compiles with a warning but seems to work:

```ml
let inline internal inPlaceAdd<[<Measure>] 'Index, ^Value when ^Value : (static member (+) : ^Value * ^Value -> ^Value)> (a: Arr<'Index, 'Value>) (b: ImArr<'Index, 'Value>) =
    let mutable i = 0;
    while i < a.Values.Length && i < b.Values.Length do
        let x = (^Value : (static member (+) : ^Value * ^Value -> ^Value)(a.Values.[i], b.Values.[i]))
        a.Values.[i] <- x
        i <- i + 1
```

Note the extremely convoluted invocation of addition, which causes compiler warning `FS0077: Member constraints with the name 'op_Addition' are given special status by the F# compiler...`. By all rights, you should be able to add values directly instead, like this:

```ml
let x = a.Values.[i] + b.Values.[i]
```

But that doesn't compile, for some reason: `A type parameter is missing a constraint 'when ( ^Value or  ^?11121) : (static member ( + ) :  ^Value *  ^?11121 ->  ^?11122)'` This looks like a compiler bug to me, but who knows.

Usage:

```ml
let a = Arr([|1; 2; 3|])
let b = ImArr([|2; 3; 4|])
Helpers.inPlaceAdd a b
printfn "%A" a.Values   // [|3; 5; 7|]
```